# AAD B2C Invite Registration Flow with App Roles

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm building an application with B2C and have been able to setup app roles and return them in signed in user claims to implement RBAC by following this guide https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/api-connector-samples/tree/main/Authorization-AppRoles.

The admins of the system will create users and assign them roles. To do this I'd like to avoid sending passwords in invitation emails, handling registration pages in my application and making users sign in after providing details.

Ideally I'd like to follow this sample invite flow https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite so an email with a link is sent out to a user, they click the link and fill in their details, B2C adds the user and signs them in. But added to this I want to include the new users app role in the encrypted token in the email link and pass this to B2C so it can post to /v1.0/users/*userId*/appRoleAssignments after creating the user. This will mean having a dynamic object in the url as well as in the body. I need to do this so the role would be included immediately in their claims on the first sign in.

Have been able to post new users and add the app roles via the Graph Api.
Cannot find an example of doing this via a custom policy. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54875609/calling-the-azure-ad-graph-api-from-an-azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy) looks like calling graph api from the custom policy isn't possible with dynamic objects in the url and body and I'll have to call into my own api before posting to Graph Api

Any advice and/or confirmation much appreciated